# Multiple update query with Multiple conditions

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

Basically I am facing an issue, both my queries are working fine, but instead of writing two queries, I want to write one query. As you can see my table name is same just update the data on condition

```js
  await getConnection()
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .update(StudentOrders)
      .set({ OrderTypes: 'Fresh' })
      .where({ allowRemote: true }).execute()
      
         
      await getConnection()
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .update(StudentOrders)
      .set({ OrderTypes: 'Old' })
      .where({ allowRemote: false }).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I can see what your obscurification language is doing, I am not sure how to translate SQL into it. However, you should easily enough. In Postgres SQL you use the `case` expression for alternatives. So:  (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/uRrrby9m))

```
update student_orders 
   set order_types = case when allow_remote
                          then 'Fresh'
                          else 'Old'
                     end ;
```

Comment: basically its TypeOrm I want to implement through typeORm query builder